# div in fluid grid jumps in size at breaking point

Tags: html, css

Code is too long to post, but essentially i have a couple divs/sections which are meant to be responsive via float-grid. They look like this:

```
            <div class="col-4">
              <section>
                <img src="https://tf-assets-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/tf-curric/WEB-DEV-001/2.6.3_challenge_responsive_layout/rey_square.png" />
                <b>Rey</b>
                <p class="expl">xxxx</p>
              </section>
            </div>
```

At 745px (give or take) the 2nd row divvies up and pushes the first `img` all the way to the right and changes in height. My guess is that it has to do with the float, but i really can't change it. 
Also, when dragging below 640px the first image appears fine, but the 2nd and all subsequent images show the title next to its image. What is causing this to happen and how do i fix it?

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@HelleW/Challenge-Star-Wars-Responsive-Design)

Comment: is your issue that the images of the characters get misaligned?

Comment: @Huangism yes, essentially. I added some info

Comment: Basically, the issue is caused by the length of your content. If you look closely, Rey's description becomes 2 lines and it is now taller than the other boxes so the stuff under it gets pushed. I suggest you ditch float and learn flex. Follow this link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ spend like an hour or 2 reading/writing it, it is not hard as long as you are willing to try it. https://repl.it/repls/FrugalGreedyNetwork I added/removed a few lines only in the css just to show you how easy it could of been. The red borders are your col-xx and they are now flex items

Comment: I'm proficient with flexbox, but this project requires float and it's grid construct, only. any other idea?

Comment: @Huangism also, editing the text via developer tools to something shorter does not fix the issue

Comment: because Finn's description is just as long, if you see a height difference between the first row boxes then it will be off

Comment: you could fix this by using `nth-child` and targeting the 4th col-4 for a given media query range and set `clear: left` but I suggest you convert this to flex because it isn't hard to do and I don't see why you have to use float

Comment: @Huangism as i said, the project requires float, and changing that is not in my power. I fixed the white space issue by changing `max-width: 100%;` to simply `width: 100%;`, but the jumping/size differences remain

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use flex, then you could fix this by using `nth-child`. The below will target the first item in every row for a 3 column layout, except for the first row which doesn't need this anyway

```
.col-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

I suggest you put this in a media query range so that it does not affect other width. If you don't put this inside a range, you might need to write extra css to override it later